# ActiveRecord .joins breaking other queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm writing a Rails API on top of a legacy database with tons of tables. The search feature gives users the ability to query around 20 separate columns spread across 13 tables. I have a number of queries that check the params to see if they need to return results. They look like this:

```
results << Company.where('city LIKE ?', "#{params[:city]}").select('id') unless params[:city].blank?
```

and they work fine. However, I just added another query that looks like this:

```
results << Company.joins("JOIN Contact ON Contact.company_id = Company.id").where("Contact.first_name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:first_name]}%").select('company_id') unless params[:first_name].blank?
```

and suddenly my first set of queries started returning null, rather than the list of IDs they had been returning. The query with the join works perfectly well whether the other queries are functional or not. When I comment the join query out, the previous queries start working again. Is there some reason the query with a join would break other queries on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the queries with a join needed to be placed above the queries without a join. I'm not sure why it behaves this way, but hopefully this helps someone else down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a particular reason why the join would be breaking your previous queries however I do have some suggestions for your query overall.

Assuming you've modelled these relationships correctly you shouldn't need to define the join manually.  On another note, you're not querying against the company at all so you can use an includes instead of a join - this will allow you to access its data without firing another query.

If you wanted to access company data (ie. query.company.name) use an includes like so:

```
Contact.includes(:company).where('first_name LIKE ?', param).select(:company_id).distinct
```

However it appears all you really want is an array of ID's (which exists on the contact model), because of this you can lighten things up and not include the company at all.

```
Contact.where('first_name LIKE ?', param).select(:company_id).distinct
```

Whenever you get stuck never forget to checkout the great resources over at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/ - they are an absolute life saver sometimes!